# Sim Card Hot Swapping Android

Tags: android, sim-card, hotswap

I am developing an android application, where without being restarting the phone the sim is replaced(hot swap).

The main objectives of this app are :

Read sim1 details and store (Done)
Hot Swap Sim1 by Sim2
Read details of Sim2 and store
The problem here is, when i hot swap, I need to either restart my phone to get sim details or I have to put the phone to Flight/Airplane mode then back to Normal mode.

Can anyone suggest me how to Read the Sim2 Details without restarting/putting in flight mode then back to normal mode?

PS: I am working with a Zentality 720-c (SPRD) Tablet, android version 6.0

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to get a phone or a tablet that supports **2 (two) SIM cards** at the same time and play with that without any hot-swapping, that may damage your SIM cards and / or your phone in the process.

Comment: The tablet that i am using actually supports two SIM cards but on the app i am developping i plan to read data from 3 sim cards (3 different operators) so i really need some Sim Multiplexing..